# Unresolved compilation with java.util.List

Tags: java, arrays

Today suddenly all my classes related to `ArrayList` stopped working with Eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0). I'm not using maven. I tried to clean the project but it had no effect. I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:     
The type ArrayList is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
   at Problem.main(Problem.java:5)
```

Even for a simple code like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> listofthings = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer>()` missing the type

Comment: @corn3lius no... The generic is already defined with `List<Integer>`

Comment: Are you importing `java.util.ArrayList` as well?

Comment: Check your compiler settings - see if it is trying to compile to an earlier java version

Comment: `Import java.util.Arraylist)` doesn't work it says: `Import java.util.Arraylist cannot be resolved`. In my previous projects I used import java.util.*; and it worked just fine. If I right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - > Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - the Execution envrironment is set to JavaSE-1.8 (jre1.8.0_91). It still doesn't work if I select Alternate JRE: jre1.8.0_91

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, a file named `ArrayList.java` in the same directory? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn
That was years ago, but if I remember well, that was the case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import this library :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;//for ArrayList
import java.util.List;//for List
```

Comment: `Import java.util.Arraylist` doesn't work it says: `Import java.util.Arraylist cannot be resolved`. In my previous projects I used import java.util.*; and it worked just fine. If I right click on project - >BuildPath - >Configure BuildPath - >Libraries tab - > Double click on JRE SYSTEM LIBRARY - the Execution envrironment is set to JavaSE-1.8 (jre1.8.0_91). It still doesn't work if I select Alternate JRE: jre1.8.0_91

Comment: of course @user2665140 because it is not correct it is **import java.util.ArrayList** and not **Import java.util.Arraylist** the upper **I** in Import and L in **Arraylist** it should not be like this get it?

Comment: @user2665140 just copie and past and it will work fine with you.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand why it still doesn't work with 
`import java.util.*` when it worked previous times. Looks like in Eclipse something was set wrong, but I can't locate it.

Comment: If I use:
`import java.util.List;`
`import java.util.ArrayList;`
it works.
But if I just use:
`import java.util.*;`
It says:
`The type Arraylist is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments<>`

Comment: @user2665140 i'm not sure, but if that avoid to set arguments like this : `new ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: @user2665140 why you avoid to use `import java.util.List; import java.util.ArrayList;` and want only `import java.util.*;` ?

Comment: I just want to understand why did it work with `import java.util.*;`, and why suddenly it stopped working. Maybe I set something wrong in Eclipse, although I can't recall such event.

Comment: mmm, i dont know @user2665140 don't think in this small things, try to move forward, if my answer help you thank you to validate please

Comment: @user2665140 Do you have your own class called `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 1):

this generic inference is allowed since java 7

```
List<Integer> listofthings = new ArrayList<>();
```

so you need to do this for lower versions:

```
List<Integer> listofthings = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: @CraigR8806 In java 7 and up - yes. In Java 6 and older it has to be explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the import

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

or change the line:

```
List<Integer> listofthings = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Good Afternoon Folks. Maybe you named the class with the library you wanted to add.

For instance,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

and then:

```
public class ArrayList {
 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<String>();

}
```